# Should it be "you've been in" or "you've been to"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, sentence-usage

Which is the correct sentence? Why?

1. It's the first time he has been **in** space.
2. It's the first time he has been **to** space.

Comment: I can't recall many examples, but I assume it's always to. In this case, "to" is more sensible too. Or I can say "I've never been *to* Vancouver, but they say it's fancy".

Comment: Are you interested in this in general, or about _space_ in specific? (That's kind of a unique case.)

Comment: I wanna know the difference between been in and to in general and in specific also

Answer (score 5):

Both are acceptable and the choice must be made based on whether you wish to emphasize the rocket flight *to* space or the experience of being *in* space.

In other words if he made the comment, "This thing feels like it's going to fall apart any second, I'm getting nervous." I might comment to my fellow astronauts, "Heh, you can tell that this is the first time he's been **to** space."

But if we were in the space station and he made the comment, "I keep feeling like I'm going to vomit.  When does it stop?"  I might comment to my fellow astonauts, "Heh, you can tell that this is the first time he's been **in** space."

Comment: Not necessarily, but usually. [Time for some music...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZgIk2b68gQ)

Comment: Probably worth pointing out on a language site: *This things feels* appears incorrectly in one of your quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct but in my experience *He has been **to** space* would be used more often. I would usually understand *space* to be a destination (rather than a [medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_medium)). If you said *He has been **in** space* I might think you were talking about a space walk - he has gone outside the spaceship into space. Think of the difference between going **to** the sea and going **in** the sea. With space you have to do both at the same time.

To summarise you go **to** a destination but you go **in** or **into** a substance, medium, building, vehicle, enclosed space, etc. Some words like *space* and *kitchen* can be either depending on the sentence. *He went **to** the kitchen, now he's **in** the kitchen*. You might say *He went **into** the kitchen* but you'd be unlikely to say *He went **in** the kitchen*. It's not wrong, it's just not used that much.